# MySQL Get only first match of a conditions between 3 columns

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, greatest-n-per-group

I am working with an API REST (NodeJS) that have access to a MySQL DB.
In this database, there is a table that looks like this (let's name it **Table_01**):

```
| C_0| C_1| C_2| C_3| 
|  1 | A1 | B1 |  1 |
|  2 | A1 | B2 |  0 |
|  3 | B1 | A1 |  0 |
|  4 | A2 | B1 |  0 |
|  5 | B2 | A1 |  1 |
|  6 | B1 | A1 |  0 |
|  7 | B3 | A1 |  0 |
|  8 | A1 | B3 |  1 |
|  9 | A3 | B1 |  0 |
| 10 | A1 | B3 |  1 |
| 11 | A1 | B1 |  0 |
```

My objective is to get the first match of a Value = 1 on C_3 for a pair of values in C_1 and C_2.

Let's put an example.

I want to know in what cases **A_1 in C_1**, have a **1 in C_3** (only the first match)

So, in this case, the result should be:

```
A1 B1 1
A1 B3 1
```

In JSON format:

```js
result = [
  {
    "C_1": "A1",
    "C_2": "B1",
    "C_3": "1",
  },
  {
    "C_1": "A1",
    "C_2": "B3",
    "C_3": "1",
  }
];
```

I don't want to receive TWO times the second one, since A1 B3 = 1 is included 2 times in the table.

I can get the result doing this:

```js
db.query('SELECT * FROM `Table_01` WHERE (`C_1` = A1 AND `C_2` = '+db.escape(value)+') AND `C_3` = 1',
  (err, res) => {
    ..
  }
);
```

But this would give me a third entry with the duplicated A1 B3 1.

Obviously in this example is not very important.. But with a table full of rows, this is important to avoid very large responses and a posterior JS filter.

Comment: The term "first match" exists only when the (unique) ordering is defined. Does ascending ordering by `C_0` is one you need?

Comment: `C_0` is my incremental Unique.  I don't understand why this has to be a condition for "first match". Thanks

Comment: Imagine unordered heap.. of bricks, for example. What brick in this heap is first?

Comment: Ok, I see. I thought SQL was ordered by default.

Comment: Strictly backward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select t.*
from table_01 t
where t.id = (
    select min(t1.id) 
    from table_01 t1 
    where t1.c_1 = t.c_1 and t1.c_2 = t.c_2 and t1.c_3 = 1 
)
```

You can also use window functions, if you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by c_1, c_2 order by id) rn
    from mytable t
    where c_3 = 1
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks. About the window functions, are they faster (in performance), than the first one?

Comment: You would need to assess that against your actual data. The first solution would take advantage of an index on `(c_1, c_2, c_3)`.